# helm hadoop version 3.2 on k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want helm chart for hadoop version 3.2 on k8s working on eks aws I tired version 2.9 on https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/hadoop and working well I want version 3.2

Comment: Hello, have you seen this Helm chart by any chance? https://github.com/chenseanxy/helm-hadoop-3

Comment: I tried this but once deployed there is issue that datanode not show namenode